# Android textedit box characters display unreadable

Tags: android, android-layout

When adding a textedit to a dialog box in an xml file, for some reason, my textedit box displays bars (i.e unreadable text) when I enter text either from a real device or simulator (see screen shot.)

Text displays fine if I do this programmatically. Anybody had this problem? And was able to resolve it?

[image]

Comment: Can you show the XML file and how you added to the dialog?

Comment: Apologies for the delay in my response. I was able to fix it after playing with the layout weight. Not sure why that would do it, but it worked.

Comment: Glad to hear. You are welcome to answer your own question below

Answer (score 0):

In conclusion, I changed the Layout Weight. Here is the xml for the EditText:

```
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="2"
        android:id="@+id/edittext_box"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="4"
        android:minWidth="40dp" />
```